# Flask nginx proxy fix duplicates headers

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn, werkzeug

I have a flask server deployed with nginx and gunicorn. I read [this](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/#proxy-setups) and have nginx setup to set these headers and have the werkzeug middleware proxy fix in place. Now the headers coming in on flask have the right ip addresses and hosts and stuff. Except for 1 small problem. The headers show up as duplicates separated by commas. Here's what I see when printing `request.headers`.

```
Host: site.com,site.com
X-Real-Ip: 12.345.67.898,12.345.67.898
X-Forwarded-For: 12.345.67.898,12.345.67.898
X-Forwarded-Proto: https,https
```

These headers, are the ones that nginx overrides. Why do they all repeat. They are repeated and divided by a comma. How can I fix this behavior?
I have the nginx config and the werkzeug middleware proxy fix done exactly is in the example.
Here's my nginx config more or less.

```
server {
    # dont worry about ssl, certbot handles that
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name site.com www.site.com;
    
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/site.sock;
        proxy_redirect off;
        
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried redirecting all the HTTP traffic to HTTPS?

Comment: i literally said in a comment that certbot handles ssl that isn't the problem

Comment: What is in the file `proxy_params`?

Comment: oh wow. just checked. it contains the same proxy_set_header that i already was setting. so i was setting them twice. that explains it thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Richard Smith solved this problem. And that was the `include proxy_params;` line. I `cat /etc/nginc/proxy_params` and it contained the exact proxy_set_header lines that where already included. Bassically it set those headers twice. I have to either delete the `include proxy_params` line or delete the manual `proxy_set_header` lines.